# execution of buy and sell signal not working properly

Tags: pine-script, trading

hi i wanted to try very simple strategy in tradingview where
buy on open on monday, sell on close on friday; 
start from 2002 to now

```
>//@version = 2
strategy("buy signal entry",overlay = true)
//1009963800 is 2002 - 01-02

t = dayofweek(time)
buysignal = plotshape(t==2 , "Up Arrow", shape.triangleup,location.belowbar,green,0,0)
sellsignal = plotshape(t==5 , "Down Arrow", shape.triangledown,location.abovebar,white,0,0)
plot(t)
if(t==2)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long)
if(t == 5)
    strategy.exit("exit", "buy")
```

for some reason, this only executes on the firstday and never sells anything after
any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.exit` without conditions for an exit (e.g. profit or loss) does nothing. In your case you shoud use `strategy.close`:

```
if(t == 5)
    strategy.close("buy")
```